# Can I consume youtube video content and play in my own custom built flash player?

Tags: youtube, swfobject

I built my own flash movie player.  now I want to consume youtube videos and play them in my own flash player, so that the end user does not see any indication that the videos are housed on youtube.  Does the youtube api allow me to do this?